# Postfix email TLS header but is not encrypted for gmail

Tags: email, ssl, encryption, smtp, postfix-mta

I have a little strange problem. I have newly configured postfix server(with dovecot). 
Everything is fine for almost all mail recievers, except for gmail's. I have this header

```
using TLSv1.2 with cipher ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 (128/128 bits)
```

in every single mail, but for google is still not encrypted and I see it with unlocked red padlock icon. And it is going to spam only for gmail.

```
Postfix v2.11.3
smtpd_tls_security_level=encrypt
```

Does anyone had the same problem ? Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use smtp_tls_security_level. smtpd_... is for incoming email; smtp_... is for outgoing email.

You can also see http://www.postfix.org/TLS_README.html#client_tls for more details.

Comment: I knew that. It's so obvious that I should use  smtp_tls_security_level, but why I didn't make it.. Thanks. It works!